# Ping monitoring program

Tags: ping, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a tool that I can use to monitor my ping time to a gaming server in real time. I've been getting lag spikes and want to watch where they are happening, how often, etc. I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux so any help is great. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try the `mtr` (or `mtr-tiny`) package, it contains the `mtr` command that continually displays in a terminal the routes and the latest ping times on each router:

```
.                                                                          Packets               Pings
Host                                                                   Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
1. 128.199.32.253                                                       0.0%    58    0.3   3.6   0.3  19.8   5.2
2. 138.197.250.78                                                       0.0%    58    0.3   1.1   0.3  22.9   3.3
3. adm-b1-link.telia.net                                                0.0%    57    0.8   0.7   0.4   1.0   0.0
4. adm-bb4-link.telia.net                                               0.0%    57   79.7  80.4  79.6  88.2   1.5
5. ldn-bb4-link.telia.net                                               0.0%    57   80.7  78.5  77.3  88.8   2.2
6. ldn-b4-link.telia.net                                                0.0%    57    7.8   8.3   7.3  22.3   2.0
7. ldn-bb3-link.telia.net                                               0.0%    57  112.2 113.3 112.1 145.0   4.6
8. prs-bb3-link.telia.net                                               0.0%    57   94.2  94.4  94.1  95.8   0.2
9. ash-bb4-link.telia.net                                               0.0%    57   94.9  94.7  94.3  97.0   0.5
10. ash-b1-link.telia.net                                                0.0%    57   94.5  94.4  94.2  94.7   0.0
11. tp-brdrbtr-02.bwi.tierpoint.net                                      0.0%    57   96.6  96.7  96.5  97.0   0.0
12. te-0-0-2-2.tp-bwi-core-rtr-01.bwi.opsmgmt.net                        0.0%    57   96.6  96.5  96.4  96.6   0.0
13. 40.142.52.27                                                         0.0%    57   97.4  97.4  97.2  97.8   0.0
14. 144-202-157-173.baltimoretechnologypark.com                          0.0%    57   99.1  99.0  98.9 100.1   0.1
15. 144-202-238-253.baltimoretechnologypark.com                          0.0%    57   98.8  98.8  98.8  99.0   0.0
16. ssd20-md.privatesystems.net                                          0.0%    57   96.9  96.9  96.9  97.1   0.0
17. host.gimpchat.com                                                    0.0%    57   97.0  96.9  96.8  99.7   0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like [smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/).

There's several ways of having it run, here's [one](http://olivermarshall.net/install-smokeping-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

Comment: Hi @SYN,  note that while that link:http://olivermarshall.net/install-smokeping-on-ubuntu-14-04/ might provide the relevant information, links can get taken down at any moment, maybe you should edit your answer to include the important information from that link?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a log file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
#-----------------------------------
# Check internet connection every minute or at a set interval
# and create log file
# If connection is not present, ping will show 100% packet loss
#--- 47.182.239.232 ping statistics ---
#1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
#-----------------------------------
while true; do

date >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
echo >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
ping  yahoo.com -c 1 >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
echo >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
sleep 60

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special application to do what you want.

Just open a `terminal` window from the Unity launcher, then in that window, type `ping` followed by the `name` of the site you wish to monitor.

Example: `ping www.ebay.com`

Use a `control-c` to stop the pings.

note: pings will not tell you **where** the problem is, just **when** the problem occurs.